# Calculate $\int_{\Gamma} \omega$ when $\omega =z(z-y)dx+xzdy-xydz$, $\Gamma=\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \cup \Gamma_3$

Tags: integration, parametrization

> Calculate $\int_{\Gamma} \omega$ when $\omega =z(z-y)dx+xzdy-xydz$
>
> $\Gamma=\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \cup \Gamma_3$
>
> $$x^2+y^2=(z-1)^2$$
>
> $x\geq0, y\geq0,z\geq0$
>
> $\Gamma_{1,2,3}$ are the intersections with planes $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$

How do I find the right parametrization?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DonAntonio it's the intersection **with** those planes with the restriction of $x\geq 0$, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths over which the integral is taken look like this:
[image]
There is a circle at the bottom and four line segments protruding upwards. The parametrisation needs five smooth pieces, but that's fine – just add the results of the five integrals together.

The circle can be parametrised in the usual way as $(\cos t,\sin t,0)$ for $0\le t<2\pi$. The line segment from $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$ can be parametrised as
$$(1,0,0)(1-t)+(0,0,1)t=(1-t,0,t)\qquad0\le t<1$$
I leave it to you to find (very) similar equations for the remaining three line segments.

Comment: Make me understand, why you wrote it in that way (vectorial): $$(1,0,0)(1-t) + (0,0,1)t = (1-t, 0, t)$$

And what did you thought of when you started to parametrize this?

Comment: @C.Cristi This is the classic two-point parametric form for a line segment.

Comment: When I have $x(t) = t-1$, $y=0$, $z=t$ What should be the intervals of integration? And also, why five integrals? shouldn't it be 3?

Comment: @C.Cristi You _could_ use three integrals, but two of those would not be smooth, complicating matters. For the two-point form I showed you, the limits of integration are always 0 and 1.

Comment: And when I do the circle integral, on $\omega$ it gives me $0$, is that okay? I don't think... I mean, with the parametrisation $(cost,sint,0)$ for $0\leq t<2\pi$

Comment: @C.Cristi 0 is not indicative of an incorrect result. It may as well be $-1$, $8$ or whatever other number.

Comment: I know, but I'm just sayin, since I'm integrating a circle on $\omega$ what is the $\omega$ signification in the drawing?

Comment: @C.Cristi $\omega$ is merely shorthand for the expression given. (I would write it $(z(z-y),xz,-xy)\,d\mathbf r$.)

Comment: The final answer is $\frac 13$?

Comment: @C.Cristi Yes.${}$

Comment: If we want to intersect with $\;x,y,z\ge0\;$ then the projection canonical circle is just $\;(\cos t,\,\sin t\,0) , 0\le t\le\color{red}{\frac\pi2}\;$ ...